# cannot change back from bridge mode?

Tags: wireless-bridge

I get my network from my ISP wirelessly. They have installed a wireless CPE (binatone WR1500N) at my roof and the router gets it power via Poe. Until today I could access my CPE by typing 192.168.5.5 in my browser.

Then I wanted to set my computer so that I can access it from my college (ssh). But my public IP address and my gateway address (private) did not match (probably ISP is using Nat).

So what I did (I don't know why), I set my CPE on bridge mode and bahm, the ethernet can now not connect to it, So i cannot come out of bridge mode. After an hour I discovered that CPE was now functioning as WiFi. But I cannot connect to that (the isp guy didn't give me password). The CPE has no button whatsoever to reset it (It's rectangular in shape with ethernet wire coming out of it)

So basically now, how to get out of bridge mode and go back to client-server mode?

Answer (score 0):

Bridge mode will have removed all routing to the device, and disabled NAT functionality. Technically it may be possible to reestablish a route to it, but I don't know for your particular model.

Usually at this stage, the simplest method to reestablish a connection to the device is to hit the reset button and start again from your settings backup, or from scratch if you haven't made one.

Instructions for your model are [here](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/binatone/wr1500n/reset-router.htm), although I can't verify them.